# Staying for a month in the Schengen Zone after my student visa expires

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, 90-180-visa-rules, student-visas

I am Mexican, currently studying in Milan with a student visa.
My visa expires on December 18th and my flight back to Mexico is on January 16th.

I want to know if I have to leave and re-enter the Schengen zone in order to have the 90-day tourist permit to stay or if it just automatically applies.

And also I was wondering if in any case I stay within the Schengen zone without leaving it before going back to Mexico, will I have any problems if I want to return to Europe?

Hope you can help me :)